# Rename [coludhq] to [cloudhq]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [coludhq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coludhq) should be renamed [cloudhq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudhq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something you could have done yourself by simply fixing the spelling mistake in the one question where this tag was used.

Comment: Ah, I didn't knew that. I thought you need to go through the admin tools to do that. Thanks!

Comment: But [tag:coludhq] still exists.

Comment: @Alex - give it 24 hours. As long as no one else adds it to a question it will disappear.